# Installed Java program submits batch file but it does not execute. Executing the same executable from the command window works

Tags: java, windows, batch-file, runtime

I have a JAVA jar program turned into a .exe then an install created with INNO Setup. The program installs and works except at the end I submit a dos command to execute a batch file to copy some files. If I run the installed program by double clicking on the file associated with it. The program runs successfully except the batch file does not run. If I open a command window and execute the same program from the command line, it runs successfully and the batch file runs successfully.

The method that runs the batch file is.

```
    public static int  moveAside()
{
    System.out.println("----MoveAside: start: " + UserDir + " TCDir: " + TCDir);
   try
   {
       String pathx = "\"" + UserDir + "\"";
       String newFileName = FilenameIn.replaceAll("/","\\\\");
       String newTCDir = TCDir.replaceAll("/","\\\\");
       String squote = "\"";
       String path = "cmd \"/c/q\" start  \"\" "   + pathx + "\\moveAside.bat " +   "C:\\IronLayer\\PERPLXDAM\\"  + " " +  newFileName  + " " + newTCDir  ;
      // ">> moveAside.out";
       System.out.println("MA: " + path + "<<<");
       Runtime rn = Runtime.getRuntime();
       Process pr = rn.exec(path);

   } catch (Exception e)
   {
       System.out.println("----Exception in MoveAside: " + e.getMessage());
       return 1;
   }
    System.out.println("----MoveAside: run successfully");

   return 0;
}
```

A typical call from the System.out.println above is:

"C:\Program Files (x86)\PERPLXDAM"\moveAside.bat C:\IronLayer\PERPLXDAM\ C:\Users\johnf\onedrive\Desktop\robin042920e.DVNC C:\Users\johnf\onedrive\Desktop\

The bat file moveAside.bat is:

```
::
::---setup remover bat
::
::  %1 - desktop directory name
::  %2 - transcode file name and path
::  %3 - desktop location
::

echo on

for /F "tokens=2" %%i in ('date /t') do set mydate=%%i
set mytime=%time%


 echo  %mydate%:%mytime% "==" PPLXCTL.cfg %1 "==" %2 =="C:\IronLayer\PERPLXDAM\"  == "desktop:         " + %3 >>"C:\IronLayer\PERPLXDAM\Hist.log" 

set local

set "_tdir = %1"
set "_tfiledir = %2"
 echo tfiledir: "%_tfiledir%"

move /Y "%2" "C:\IronLayer\PERPLXDAM\"

move /Y "%3PPLXCTL.cfg" "C:\IronLayer\PERPLXDAM\"

::exit
```

(the exit is commented out so the command window does not disappear while I am debugging.)

An Icon is associated with the .DVNC file extent and double clicking on one of those files triggers the program.  But the batch file does not run executing it that way, the rest of the program runs fine, just not the final bat file.

Again, if I execute the same .exe from the command line the program works and the .bat runs successfully and the files are copied off the desktop.

Comment: What error messages and output is printed?

Comment: There is no error message and nothing  is printed. When viewing the command window output (ISSO setup install using CMD mode). There is a message that shows the command procedure is successfully run (no error back from the cmd submit). But there is no evidence that the bat file ran. If I open a command window and cut and paste what I printed out as the argument to the rn.exe the bat file runs successfully.

Answer (score 0):

You invoke the Runtime.exec() method. The method returns a Process instance, and in [it's documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Process.html) you can read

*By default, the created process does not have its own terminal or console. All its standard I/O (i.e. stdin, stdout, stderr) operations will be redirected to the parent process, where they can be accessed via the streams obtained using the methods getOutputStream(), getInputStream(), and getErrorStream(). The parent process uses these streams to feed input to and get output from the process. Because some native platforms only provide limited buffer size for standard input and output streams, failure to promptly write the input stream or read the output stream of the process may cause the process to block, or even deadlock.*

So it is likely your process is started by the OS but gets blocked due to I/O restrictions. Get around that by reading the STDOUT and STDERR streams until your process finishes. One good programming model is visible at https://www.baeldung.com/run-shell-command-in-java